# Match value in two files and replace values in columns

Tags: awk

The purpose is to check if values for column 3 and 4 in file1 match with column 1 in file2.

If any value match do:

1) Replace values in file2 for column 2 and 3 using the information of file1 columns 5 and 6

2) Replace string ($1,1,5) and string ($1,6,5) in file2 with values of columns 7 and 8 from file1

3) Add character R for lines replaced and O for lines not replaced.

**file1**

```
2,100,31431,37131,999991.70,0000000.30,11111,22222,3
3,100,31431,37471,111113.20,1111111.30,22222,33333,4
```

**file2**

```
3143137113 318512.50 2334387.50 100
3143137131 318737.50 2334387.50 100
3143137201 319612.50 2334387.50 100
3143137471 322987.50 2334387.50 100
3143137491 323237.50 2334387.50 100
```

**Desired output:**

```
31431,37113,318512.50,2334387.50,100,O
11111,22222,999991.70,0000000.30,100,R
31431,37201,319612.50,2334387.50,100,O
22222,33333,111113.20,1111111.30,100,R
31431,37491,323237.50,2334387.50,100,O
```

**I tried**

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
FNR==NR { 
f1_56[$3$4]=($5 OFS $6)
f1_78[$3$4]=($7 OFS $8)
          next
        }
{$(NF+1)="O"}
$1 in f1_56 {
  split(f1_56[$1], a, OFS)
  $2 = a[1]
  $3 = a[2]
  split(f1_78[$1], a, OFS)
  $1=a[1] OFS a[2]
  $NF="R"
} 1
' FS=, file1 FS=' ' file2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
FNR==NR { 
    f1_5[$3$4]=$5
    f1_6[$3$4]=$6
    f1_78[$3$4]=$7 OFS $8
    next
}
$1 in f1_78{
    $(NF+1)="R"
    $2=f1_5[$1]
    $3=f1_6[$1]
    $1=f1_78[$1]
    print
    next
}
{
    $(NF+1)="O"
    $1=substr($1,1,5) OFS substr($1,6,5)
} 
1 ' FS=, file1 FS=' ' file2
```

`FS=,` before files equals to switch `-F,` and equals to `FS=","` in BEGIN block.
`substr` is for Sub String.
Your own code takes too much efforts, combine and then split again, might as well just use one more variable to store another field.
You're in the right direction though, making good progress.

Try slow down, read [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/), and think. You can download it first.

Put same code in one line:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}FNR==NR {f1_5[$3$4]=$5;f1_6[$3$4]=$6;f1_78[$3$4]=$7 OFS $8;next}$1 in f1_78{$(NF+1)="R";$2=f1_5[$1];$3=f1_6[$1];$1=f1_78[$1];print;next}{$(NF+1)="O";$1=substr($1,1,5) OFS substr($1,6,5)} 1 ' FS=, file1 FS=' ' file2
```

It's the same as:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR==NR {f1_5[$3$4]=$5;f1_6[$3$4]=$6;f1_78[$3$4]=$7 OFS $8;next}$1 in f1_78{$(NF+1)="R";$2=f1_5[$1];$3=f1_6[$1];$1=f1_78[$1];print;next}{$(NF+1)="O";$1=substr($1,1,5) OFS substr($1,6,5)} 1 ' file1 FS=' ' file2
```

also the same as:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {f1_5[$3$4]=$5;f1_6[$3$4]=$6;f1_78[$3$4]=$7 OFS $8;next}$1 in f1_78{$(NF+1)="R";$2=f1_5[$1];$3=f1_6[$1];$1=f1_78[$1];print;next}{$(NF+1)="O";$1=substr($1,1,5) OFS substr($1,6,5)} 1 ' OFS=, file1 FS=' ' file2
```

In effect, same as:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {f1_5[$3$4]=$5;f1_6[$3$4]=$6;f1_78[$3$4]=$7 OFS $8;next}$1 in f1_5{$(NF+1)="R";$2=f1_5[$1];$3=f1_6[$1];$1=f1_78[$1];print;next}{$(NF+1)="O";$1=substr($1,1,5) OFS substr($1,6,5)} 1 ' FS=, OFS=, file1 FS=' ' file2
```

You can see us put separator variables here and there, sometimes use `-F`, sometimes inside the `BEGIN` block, or sometimes before or between reading files, or even mix these, that's because of the answerer's preference and/or in some cases for concise's sake.